# why Httpclient not working in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get data from the server and show in `dropdown` .but I am getting an error in while fetching data from the server.
here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsydti

```
 ngOnInit(){
    console.log('init')
   this.dropdownService.getBankData().subscribe((res)=>{
     console.log(res);
   })
  }
```

**service code**

```
getBankData(){
   return this.http.get<DropDownModel[]>(`{this.DOMAIN_URL}`)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use https instead of http, i have made the changes here

```
@Injectable()
export class DropDownService {
   private DOMAIN_URL ='https://biz.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/bankifsc/getlist'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getBankData(){
   return this.http.get<any[]>(this.DOMAIN_URL)
  }

}
```

also access res.data to get your data

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-batt5c?file=app%2Fdropdowndata.service.ts)**